# Gaussian Kernel Density Estimation - units?

Tags: python, kernel-density

I have a following code:

```
def calculate_density_and_isophotes(x,y, title="", density_levels= None):
    kde = gaussian_kde([x, y])
    kde.set_bandwidth(bw_method=0.25)

    # Define the grid on which to evaluate the density
    grid_size = 100
    x_grid = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), grid_size)
    y_grid = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), grid_size)

    x_mesh, y_mesh = np.meshgrid(x_grid, y_grid)
    xy_coordinates = np.vstack([x_mesh.ravel(), y_mesh.ravel()])
    z = kde(xy_coordinates)
    z = z.reshape(x_mesh.shape)

    plt.imshow(z, origin='lower', extent=[min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)], cmap='viridis', norm=colors.LogNorm())
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    # Find contours
    contours = plt.contour(x_mesh, y_mesh, z, levels=density_levels)
    plt.show()

    return z, contours
```

`x,y` are points' coordinates in *kpc*, of length = 448336. What would be the unit of density level? I don't understand how `kde` works below the surface. My density levels are around "0.007", I thought it would be "points per kpc", but I was told that this value is way too small and that does seem too small. Why is that value that small?